# Setting params for an inflated view inside a RelativeLayout, but getting classcastexception

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi i'm trying to add a layout programmatically using the inflater (it's a simple TextView). The parent of the inflated view is a RelativeLayout which is in a ScrollView. My problem is that I'm trying to place the new view under its header (which is in the RelativeLayout) using params.addRule and view.setLayoutParams(), but I'm getting a classcast exception: `11-12 13:06:57.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10965): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams`, even though the parent of the view is clearly a RelativeLayout. Any thoughts?

I'm thinking it's because the RelativeLayout is nested in a scrollview, but I don't understand why it would do this since the direct parent of the view I'm adding is a RelativeLayout.

```
    _innerLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.innerRelativeLayout);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getLayoutInflater();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comments, _innerLayout);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.commentsHeader);
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a non null `View` as the root with the `inflate()` method the `View` returned will actually be the `View` passed as the root in the method. So, in your case `view` is the `_innerLayout` `RelativeLayout` which has as a parent a `ScrollView`, which is an extension of `FrameLayout`(which will explain the `LayoutParams`).

So either use the current inflate method, but look for the view in the returned view:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comments, _innerLayout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.commentsHeader);
(view.findViewByid(R.id.theIdOfTextView)).setLayoutParams(params);
```

or use another version of `inflate()`(which doesn't attach he inflated view and manually add it along with proper `LayoutParams`):

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comments, _innerLayout, false);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.commentsHeader);
view.setLayoutParams(params);
_innerLayout.addView(view);
```

Comment: Nice! This works. Although it does seem VERY counterintuitive for inflate() to return what you passed as a parameter.

Comment: @Gak2 It's a bit counter intuitive but there are also the layouts with `merge` as the root tag which would need to return something(or use some other convention for the return).