# Setting gravity of a layout inflated object while adding it to a view

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to inflate inflater_layout.xml and add it to activity_main.xml.
Can anyone let me know how can I assign the gravity for the view object of inflater_layout.xml while i am adding it to activity_main.xml?

inflater_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Hello I'm inflated"
android:textSize="40sp"
android:id="@+id/toBeInflated"
/>
```

activity_main.xml (Contains a listview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id = "@+id/relative"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"         tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id = "@android:id/list">
</ListView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
ListView l;
String[] days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
LayoutInflater inflater;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    l = getListView();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_view_element, days);
    l.setAdapter(adapter);
    inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    l.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
    View inf = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_layout,r);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}
}
```

This is the outcome:

[image: This is the outcome:]

Comment: Would it be a solution to have the `TextView` as invisible/gone(takes no space) in your `RelativeLayout` in your `activity_main.xml`, and make it visible whenever you want it to? Else, you would need to add some LayoutParams to your TextView in your java code.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on adding LayoutParams?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be achieved by adding `LayoutParams` to the inflated `View`:

```
//small change, attachToRoot = false:
View inf = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_layout,r, false);
//LayoutParams always refer to the parent of the actual view:
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp  = new    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//example Rule: 
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
inf.setLayoutParams(lp);
r.addView(inf) //because we haven't added it yet.
```

Maybe also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19937050/4908802) for an explanation for the `attachToRoot = false`.